# OLSR mobile routing protocol

Tags: routing, mobile, ad-hoc-wireless, olsr

In OLSR we have the MPR - Multi Point Relays and MS - Multi Point Relay Selector. During the topology control messages flood, each MPR floods its MS set. Based on the MS set info of each node, every node builds the routing table. Is it possible to route if the MPR sets were flooded instead of the MS set?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A TC (Topology Control) message sent by a node *x* contains a list of all symmetric neighbors of the node *x*, not just the nodes that have selected *x* as a MPR.  So your question contains a wrong assumption.

Including only MPRs or MSs in a TC message wouldn't allow all nodes in the network to get full topology information about the whole network.